# not building with ./build_native.sh and android- ndk-r8 in cocos2d-x

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I have downloaded the source code for a projet in cocos2d-x.

I am using the `./build_native.sh` from the **Hello World** example, which is sure it works.

Yet again I am getting this error when compiling:

```
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile++ thumb  : cocos2d <= CCGrabber.cpp
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp: In constructor 'cocos2d::CCGrabber::CCGrabber()':
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp:46:32: error: 'glGenFramebuffersOES' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp: In member function 'void cocos2d::CCGrabber::grab(cocos2d::CCTexture2D*)':
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp:61:47: error: 'glBindFramebufferOES' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp:65:26: error: 'glFramebufferTexture2DOES' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp:68:63: error: 'glCheckFramebufferStatusOES' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp: In member function 'void cocos2d::CCGrabber::beforeRender(cocos2d::CCTexture2D*)':
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp:88:47: error: 'glBindFramebufferOES' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp: In member function 'void cocos2d::CCGrabber::afterRender(cocos2d::CCTexture2D*)':
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp:113:50: error: 'glBindFramebufferOES' was not declared in this scope
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp: In destructor 'virtual cocos2d::CCGrabber::~CCGrabber()':
jni/../../libs/cocos2dx/effects/CCGrabber.cpp:127:35: error: 'glDeleteFramebuffersOES' was not declared in this scope
```

I searched and found [this](http://blog.plicatibu.com/how-to-solve-problems-with-build_native-sh-and-android-ndk-r7-on-cocos2d-x/) sollution. But it does not work for me. I am still getting the same error. Maybe it is different in ndk-r8 whilst the sollution is for ndk-r7.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your android sdk version must bigger than 2.2.because from 2.2,the android begin to support opengl es 2.0,and the cocos2d-x 2.0 use the opengles 2.0 to render

Comment: bigger or equal or only bigger? because I am using 2.2 (api 8). I will check it again, though. Thanks.